# Problem binding to port 80: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6

Tags: apache2, ssl, letsencrypt

I have 2 projects running on different ports - 80 and 8005 on the same server. These ports point to example1.com and example2.com respectively. I installed SSL certificate for example1.com using https://tecadmin.net/install-lets-encrypt-create-ssl-ubuntu/ and it worked. However when I tried for example2.com, I got this error - `Problem binding to port 80: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6.`

I am guessing it needs example2.com to be port 80, is there a workaround this? How can I install a SSL certificate for example2.com?

This is how /sites-enabled look like

`example1.com-le-ssl.conf  example1.com.conf  example2.com.conf`

example1.com-le-ssl.conf -

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName example1.com
        ServerAlias www.example1.com
        ServerAdmin example1@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example1/public

        <Directory /var/www/html/example1/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
       </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

example1.com.conf -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName example1.com
        ServerAlias www.example1.com
        ServerAdmin example1@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example1/public

        <Directory /var/www/html/example1/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
       </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example1.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example1.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

example2.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName example2.com
        ServerAlias www.example2.com
        #ServerAdmin example2@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2/public

        <Directory /var/www/html/example2/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8001>


        ServerName example2.com
        ServerAlias www.example2.com
        #ServerAdmin example2@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2/public

        <Directory /var/www/html/example2/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

             SSLEngine on

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You need to use the Apache installer for it, which will preconfigure everything.  Try referring to https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-apache

Comment: I am got 'Congratulations! You have successfully enabled
https://naturalobsessionnigeria.com (which is example2.com in my question)' after following the article. When I visited the page, it redirects to the contents on example1.com (in real life - www.70shops.com).

Comment: You cleared your browser cache before attempting to test this, yes?  Browser caching usually is one of the main problems when debugging these things.

Comment: I am testing in incognito and it’s the same. See this, https://naturalobsessionnigeria.com/ redirects to the contents of https://70shops.com. Kindly visit the urls and see if you can make any sense out of this problem